# Facebook Authentication Example CSRF

Tags: php, facebook, authentication, csrf

The Facebook authentication example given at http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/ tries to prevent CSRF by inserting a random grouping of information into the `status` part of the auth_request.  When that auth_request returns, the code checks to make sure that same random group has been returned with the request.  How does that precent CSRF?

The code:

```
<?php 

   $app_id = "YOUR_APP_ID";
   $app_secret = "YOUR_APP_SECRET";
   $my_url = "YOUR_URL";

   session_start();
   $code = $_REQUEST["code"];

   if(empty($code)) {
     $_SESSION['state'] = md5(uniqid(rand(), TRUE)); //CSRF protection
     $dialog_url = "http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=" 
       . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($my_url) . "&state="
       . $_SESSION['state'];

     echo("<script> top.location.href='" . $dialog_url . "'</script>");
   }

   if($_REQUEST['state'] == $_SESSION['state']) {
     $token_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?"
       . "client_id=" . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($my_url)
       . "&client_secret=" . $app_secret . "&code=" . $code;

     $response = file_get_contents($token_url);
     $params = null;
     parse_str($response, $params);

     $graph_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=" 
       . $params['access_token'];

     $user = json_decode(file_get_contents($graph_url));
     echo("Hello " . $user->name);
   }
   else {
     echo("The state does not match. You may be a victim of CSRF.");
   }

 ?>
```

The bit of information is added to the request here:

```
 if(empty($code)) {
     $_SESSION['state'] = md5(uniqid(rand(), TRUE)); //CSRF protection
     $dialog_url = "http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=" 
       . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($my_url) . "&state="
       . $_SESSION['state'];

     echo("<script> top.location.href='" . $dialog_url . "'</script>");
   }
```

And checked here:

```
 if($_REQUEST['state'] == $_SESSION['state'])
```

How does ensuring they have the same "state" ensure no CSRF?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The hash (or state) is generated by you for each request to the web service (Facebook) and stored in the session on your server. This hash is sent with the request to Facebook from your website. Facebook sends the exact same hash back as a parameter on the response.

All you do is check if the hash generated before the request matches the one in the response.

```
   MyWebsite   |    Facebook
---------------+-----------------
               |
Generate $hash |
  Store $hash  |
               |
             $hash
    ----------------------->
               |
             $hash
    <-----------------------
               |
  Check $hash  |
```

This prevents CSRF because the hash is different for each request. Obviously, if you use the same string for each request, anyone who knows (or guesses) it will be able to forge a response.

Once the request is complete, check the hash from the session and the hash in the response both match. If they don't match, it's likely to be a forged response. After you check, clear the value from the session as you won't be needing it again.

In general cases (not just Facebook's implementation), it's often wise to also store a timeout for the hash. This will prevent a hash from an incomplete request being used/exploited at a later date. There is no single time that will fit all applications and cases, but in the case of a secondary request/action like this, 30s-1 minute would do.

Comment: @Roman There are plenty of attack and prevention examples on the internet. [OWASP](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)#Examples), [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery#Example_and_characteristics), [Jeff's blog](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/10/preventing-csrf-and-xsrf-attacks.html)

Comment: Thanks, I've already looked at those but still having trouble figuring out how exactly an attack would work with facebook if we omit state from the exchanges.

Comment: @Roman It totally depends on your implementation of the redirect URL. If it's open to simply putting values into the query string to process the login (and possibly do other things), then you should use the state to check if the request originated from an authorised source