# Will the auth work without state at the SESSION? 

Tags: php, csrf, facebook-authentication

I saw similar question [Facebook Authentication Example CSRF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7354110/facebook-authentication-example-csrf) and they say "The hash (or state) is generated by you for each request to the web service (Facebook) and stored in the session on your server. This hash is sent with the request to Facebook from your website. Facebook sends the exact same hash back as a parameter on the response."

Does it mean that without state at the SESSION the auth won't work?

Comment: Paragraph breaks would be useful here.

Comment: Once I edited the question, could someone up vote it back please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few months ago i made this type of login. It may probably work without it, but it is ABSOLUTELY NECESSARY to use that method for CSRF protection.

Comment: I'm hoping to receive answers to all of my questions, especcialy the main one if it is spossible. How did the 'state' come into GET at facebook auth? And if you, @DMCS would check my profile, you would see that I do mark good answers, even if sometimes they do not answer my whole question, but a part of it.

Comment: You should not ask more than one question at a time or post follow up question after follow up.  It's not fair the users of Stackoverflow who are here on their own time (not gettin paid) and offering free advice.

Comment: I think that anyone who wants to answer and knows the answer answers whatever he can and so do I. I didn't see anything that says something about multiple questions, moreover I think that those questions can only help someone who is not familiar for instance with DbC. Finally, this time I really do not see a reason to rank down my questions, unless multiple questions are dissalowed, which I'm not sure about.

Comment: Update: I saw this http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39223/one-post-with-multiple-questions-or-multiple-posts . I will ask multiple questions instead of this one.